# How to make a div overlaying another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with Bootstrap 3 and I wanted to make a row like this:

[image]

So here is how I tried:

```
<div class="news-section">  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 news-card">
            <div class="news-content">
                <div class="news-para">
                    Lorem ipsum ... 
                </div>
                <div class="news-image">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-6 news-card">
            <div class="news-content">
                <div class="news-para">
                    Lorem ipsum ...
                </div>
                <div class="news-image">
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I don't really know how to make the `news-image` div which contains the `image`, overlay the `news-content` div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

- Using `relative` positioning on the `parent`.
- using `absolute` positioning on the `child` and adjusting the position.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #dbdbdb;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  left: 10px;
  top: -10px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 135px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/995/536/354.jpg?hmac=kARkIcQD-5FYzmRwd89uPn6yxoJvaCg43bkO-kABGGE" alt="" class="child">
  <span class="text">Lorem text</span>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle code**](https://jsfiddle.net/tw5defuo/)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at this issue I can suggest you use `position:relative` for the parent element (which is the `news-content`).
Then add `position:absolute` for the child element here (which is the `news-image`). After that **offset** the child element with **margins** to position them according to the picture above.